# C# Texbox's 'MaxLength' Property - Faults (Winform)

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, textbox

There might be some workaround for this one - however, I'm not sure what it is at the moment. After setting the MaxLength property of a textbox, I am unable to *manually* exceed the `MaxLength` of the `textBox`. On the other hand, if I were to create a loop which programmatically added characters to the textbox - this loop could exceed the maxLength property.

```
    textBox1.MaxLength = 5;  // I am now unable to manually type in more than 5 chars.

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
    textBox1.AppendText("D");
    }

// Textbox now holds 20 chars.
```

Without having to write more lines of code to take a portion of this data, is there a way to ensure that the maxlength property is not exceeded?

Regards,
Evan

Comment: add the corresponding tag to the question please

Comment: I don't see why you would even create such a scenario?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The only way someone will get past your `MaxLength` property is by getting the source. Other than that, I don't see the issue you're bringing up.

Comment: I just have many method which try to append text to this box and I wanted to ensure they didn't exceed a limit. I'll just write a function to do so -

Comment: @Evan - This property is applicable only when the TextMode property is set to TextBoxMode.SingleLine or TextBoxMode.Password and this property cannot be set by themes or style sheet themes. Have you considered these things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MaxLength: Gets or sets the maximum number of characters the user can type or paste into the text box control. (Forms)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx and Gets or sets the maximum number of characters allowed in the text box. (web) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength.aspx

In other words, that's the point of MaxLength - it's all about controlling user input.  Since you own the textbox to begin with, you don't need to set your own hard programmatic restrictions.

So in short, no - you can't change this behavior without overriding some other functionality - for instance on OnChanged - or adding the conditional tests like those shown by Ben and Sres.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength.aspx):

> In code, you can set the value of the
>   Text property to a value that has a
>   length greater than the value
>   specified by the MaxLength property.
>   This property only affects text
>   entered into the control at run time.

If you want to prevent `Text` from being longer than `MaxLength`, some extra code *is* needed.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 5; 

for (int i = 0; i < 20 && i < textBox1.MaxLength; i++)
{
    textBox1.AppendText("D");
}
```

Not sure if that counts as "more lines of code" but it's a pretty simple extra check.

Comment: The loop was just an example of how easy it is to bypass this property. I have many different methods throughout my code where this textbox is being appended and I need to ensure it does not exceed the MaxLength property previously set. I do not want to have to alter each method manually. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 5;

while(textBox1.Text.Length <= textBox1.MaxLength)
    textBox1.AppendText ("D");
```

This should do it I believe

Answer (score 1):

`MaxLength` property prevent user to type more than `n` characters. but when you set the `Text` property programatically,your textbox will show the value of its `Text` property even if its length exceed the value `MaxLength`

so you have to check if your loop exceed the maxlength or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know setting the maximum width of a textbox only enforce this restriction to end user who is entering values thorough UI. This restriction  doesn't apply on code

Answer (score 0):

MaxLength is used when you don't want the user to be able to input more than the assigned amount. However, programatically, it can be overridden. This is what append text does:

```
public void AppendText(string text)
{
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        int start;
        int length;
        this.GetSelectionStartAndLength(out start, out length);
        try
        {
            int endPosition = this.GetEndPosition();
            this.SelectInternal(endPosition, endPosition, endPosition);
            this.SelectedText = text;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (base.Width == 0 || base.Height == 0)
            {
                this.Select(start, length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method, and use it to append text instead of .AppendText()

```
void Main()
{
    var t = new TextBox();
    t.MaxLength=5;
    t.Text = "123";
    t.AppendTextRespectMaxLength("456789");
    t.Text.Dump(); // prints 12345
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AppendTextRespectMaxLength(this TextBox textbox,string newText)
    {
        if(textbox.Text.Length + newText.Length <= textbox.MaxLength)
        {
            textbox.Text += newText;
        }
        else
        {
            var remaining = textbox.MaxLength - textbox.Text.Length;
            var subPortion = newText.Substring(0,remaining);
            textbox.Text += subPortion;
        }
    }
}
```